# make jquery extensible to show and hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following for the start of a menu to show a hidden div when a button is hovered over, but would like to be able to create more buttons and associated divs without repeating the same jquery and just changing id names.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#show, #show2 {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #002061;
    color: white;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 16px #001031;

}
</style>


<button id="show_div">x</button>
<button id="show_div2">y</button>

<div id="show">show</div>
<div id="show2">show 2</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_div").mouseover(function() { 
        $("#show").css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("#show_div").mouseout(function() { 
        $("#show").css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
    $("#show").mouseover(function() { 
        $("#show").css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("#show").mouseout(function() { 
        $("#show").css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });

    $("#show_div2").mouseover(function() { 
        $("#show2").css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("#show_div2").mouseout(function() { 
        $("#show2").css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
    $("#show2").mouseover(function() { 
        $("#show2").css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("#show2").mouseout(function() { 
        $("#show2").css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
});
</script>
```

I've been able to take some steps to make it work (see below) but have not been able to make it work on more than one button. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<script>
var arr = [ "#showMe", "#showMe2" ];
jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
    $("#x").mouseover(function() { 
        $(val).css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("#x").mouseout(function() { 
        $(val).css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
    $(val).mouseover(function() { 
        $(val).css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $(val).mouseout(function() { 
        $(val).css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you could use class selector for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, this is what I ended up with:

***CSS***

```
<style>
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #002061;
    color: white;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 16px #001031;
}
</style>
```

***JS***

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("[id^=show]").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#div"+ this.id.split("show")[1]).css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("[id^=show]").mouseleave(function() { 
        $("#div"+ this.id.split("show")[1]).css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
    $("[id^=div]").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#div"+ this.id.split("div")[1]).css('visibility','visible').css('opacity','1'); 
    });
    $("[id^=div]").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#div"+ this.id.split("div")[1]).css('visibility','hidden').css('opacity','0'); 
    });
});
</script>
```

***html***

```
<button id="show1">x</button>
<button id="show2">y</button>

<div class="menu" id="div1">show</div>
<div class="menu" id="div2">show 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You want to go banally simple?**

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OvUMuXIc/2/edit)***

```
$("[id^=show]").hover(function() {
   $("#div"+ this.id.split("show")[1]).stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

the CSS needed:

```
#div1, #div2 {
    position: absolute;
                        /* remove CSS animations, opacity, */
    display:none;       /* and use DISPLAY instead of visibility */
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #002061;
    color: white;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 16px #001031;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="show1">x</button>
<button id="show2">y</button>

<div id="div1">show</div>
<div id="div2">show 2</div>
```

---

Otherwise...

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OvUMuXIc/1/edit)***

```
$("button[id^=show]").hover(function( e ) {
   var N = this.id.replace(/^\D+/g,'');
   var mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter" ; // true if mouseenter, false if mouseleave
   $("#div"+N).css({
     visibility: mEnt ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
     opacity   : mEnt ? 1 : 0
   }); 
});
```

it will grab the number `N` out of i.e: `#show1` and target the desired `#div1`

Or the same like:

```
$("button[id^=show]").hover(function( e ) {
   var m = e.type.match('t');
   $("#div"+ this.id.split("show")[1]).css({visibility:m?'visible':'hidden',opacity:mEnt?1:0}); 
});
```

---

Comment: This almost works for what I need. However, div1 and div2 should remain visible when the mouse is hovering over them and be hidden when the mouse leaves. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

'Yeah Use class selector and write your code like

```
<button class="main_class" id="show_div1">x</button>
<button class="main_class" id="show_div2">y</button>
```

`<div id="show">show1</div>`
 `<div id="show2">show2</div>`

In jquery code you can use :

```
$('.main_class').mouseover(function(event) {
 var first=event.target.id;
 var second="show"+first.slice(8);
   $("#"+second).show();
});
```

There would be similar type of code in mouseout event instead of show() function you can use hide() and it can be used for any number of elements.